# Displaying a function output directly to a QtextBrowser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

im fairly new to coding even more at object oriented python so please bear with me.

Im trying to build a GUI for a program i coded before using PyQt5.
I've designed my forms at Qt Designer then used `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x [FILENAME].ui -o [FILENAME].py` to get the file as .py.

in order to avoid to change the file, im using another python file to call the form.py file and my program.py and build everything there

```
import sys 
from myform import Ui_MainWindow
from mydialog1 import Ui_Dialog as Dlog_1
from mydialog2 import Ui_Dialog as Dlog_2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from myprogram import *

class Prog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Prog, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        self.ui.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self.about)

        self.ui.textBrowser.append(show())

    def about(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Dlog_1()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.ui.Adicionar_3.clicked.connect(dialog.close)
        dialog.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        dialog.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Prog()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Im trying to display the output from a function (from myprogram) to a QTextBrowser widget as it can be seen `self.ui.textBrowser.append(show())` although this works with plain text for example ("test") it wont work with a function.

the function show() is defined as the following

```
def show():
    global empresas
    info = ["Nome da empresa", "Site da empresa", "Montante investido"]
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        try:
            gen = ((k, v[0], v[1]) for k, v in empresas.items())
            ename, esite, evalue = zip(*gen)
            valid = True
        except ValueError:
            print('Não existem empresas para mostrar. Introduza mais empresas')
            return
    print("")
    a = ('|{}{:^30}{}| |{}{:^30}{}| |{}{:^30}{}|'.format(c['g'],info[0],c['d'],c['g'],info[1],c['d'],c['g'],info[2],c['d']))
    print("+" + "=" * (len(a)-32) + "+")
    print(a)
    print("+" + "=" * (len(a)-32) + "+")
    for y in range(0,len(ename)):
       if y % 2 == 0:   
           print(f'|{ename[y]:^30}| |{esite[y]:^30}| |{evalue[y]:^17.3f}Milhões de',simb, '|') 
           print("+" + "-" * (len(a)-32) + "+")
       elif y % 2 == 1:
           print(f'|{ename[y]:^30}| |{esite[y]:^30}| |{evalue[y]:^17.3f}Milhões de',simb, '|') 
           print("+" + "-" * (len(a)-32) + "+") 
    return
```

This function basicly prints an organized table with all the items from a dictionary to the console.
Is there a way that allows me to print the same type of output to a QtextBrowser as it would look on the console?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Publish the modules `myform.py`,` mydialog1.py` and the module where you build the `empresas`

Comment: By publishing you mean pasting the code on my post?

Comment: Yes, pasting the code on post

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to alter your `show` function to return a string instead of directly printing it, you could use stdout redirection for that. Basically this just tells `print` to write into your own buffer, which you can afterwards flush into the actual target that the string should go to:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

# in __init__ :
f = io.StringIO()   # in-memory string buffer

with redirect_stdout(f):
    # everything printed in here will go to f
    show()    

# now reroute everything written to f to textBrowser
self.ui.textBrowser.append(f.getvalue())
```